# How to get the Id of an element from <select> in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a function handleSubmit(event){}. How can I get the id of a selected option?

```
<select id="category">
   <option id="1">Travel</option>
   <option id="2">Auto Loan</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you should use value instead of ID. But if you badly need the ID of the selected option then you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43222753/4610740)-

```
  handleChange = (event) => {
      const index = event.target.selectedIndex;
      const optionElement = event.target.childNodes[index];
      const optionElementId = optionElement.getAttribute('id');

      console.log(optionElementId);
  }
```

And the select list is-

```
<select onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <option id="1">Travel</option>
    <option id="2">Autoloan</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

`HTMLSelectElement` element has [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) property. Using it and list of children you can get child's attribute:

```
<select id="category" onChange={this.selectChanged}>
    <option id="1">Travel</option>
    <option id="2">Auto Loan</option>
</select>
```

---

```
selectChanged(event){
    const select = event.target;
    const id = select.children[select.selectedIndex].id;
    //now you can store the id's value to state or somewhere else
}
```

If you need to get `id` in form submit handler you have to find `select` by id, then do the same:

```
onSubmit(event) {
    const form = event.target;
    const select = form.elements.namedItem('category');
    const id = select.children[select.selectedIndex].id;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `value`, for example create this state and function

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState("1");
const handleChange = (e) => { setCategory(e.target.value) }
```

then you can do it like this

```
<select value={category} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <option value="1">Travel</option>
    <option value="2">Autoloan</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to reactjs.org https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag
the `<select>` element has a little different in react than HTML.
In HTML, `<select>` creates a drop-down list. For example, this HTML creates a drop-down list of flavors:

```
<select>
  <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
  <option value="lime">Lime</option>
  <option selected value="coconut">Coconut</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
</select>
```

Note that the Coconut option is initially ***selected***, because of the ***selected*** attribute. React, instead of using this selected attribute, uses a ***value*** attribute on the root `select` tag. This is more convenient in a controlled component because you only need to update it in one place. For example:

```
class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 'coconut'};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your favorite flavor is: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite flavor:
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: e.target.id will return the id of the select element not the option element.